# What is correct usage of e.g. [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys:count:] under ARC?

Tags: macos, cocoa

I'm unsure how to correctly use `[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys:count:]` together with ARC (automatic reference counting). The C arrays require some special modifier, otherwise they receive warning right away. What is a correct example?

Or, asked the other way around, is this safe usage?

```
@implementation NSArray (CreateDictionaryUsingBlock)

- (NSDictionary *)dictionaryWithKeysUsing:(id (^)(id obj))block
{
  NSUInteger n = [self count];
  __autoreleasing id *keys = (__autoreleasing id *)malloc(n*sizeof(id));
  __autoreleasing id *objects = (__autoreleasing id *)malloc(n*sizeof(id));

  for(int i = 0; i<n; i++) {
    id object = [self objectAtIndex:i];
    keys[i] = block(object);
    objects[i] = object;
  }

  NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects
                                                         forKeys:keys
                                                           count:n];

  free(keys);
  free(objects);

  return dictionary;
}

@end
```